# How to Concatenate 2 rows in Mysql where a certain column is DIstinct

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I Have a DB table named calendar where i have events and there dates saved. In the Image below i have dates saved and the p_id's value can be repeated. i need to get a row that will have a distinct p_id and the dates and days would be concatenated. For E.g at the moment i have 2 rows with p_id = 2 
i would want a row that will have the following result

```
DAT        DAYS
-----      -----
 19        Wednesday
 10,26     Monday,Monday
```

I have been trying to do this since the past 3 hours and couldn't find a valuable solution. I'd be glad if someone could help :)

[image: Image of the Database Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p_id, GROUP_CONCAT(dat), GROUP_CONCAT(days) FROM calendar GROUP BY p_id
```

Comment: This Worked Ty :)